# How to extract image/screenshot from an email in JWebServices for Exchange?

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

The question is simple however I have no idea how to tackle it. I have to extract images/screenshots from an email (Message in jwebservices). It is worth noting that `.hasAttachments()` returns false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted jwebservices support and it turns when you're iterating over messages you can't just cast Item to Message object, but you have to obtain it through service object, i.e.

```
FindItemResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = service.findItem(StandardFolder.INBOX, MessagePropertyPath.getAllPropertyPaths(), unReadMessages);
            for(Item item : response.getItems()) {
                if(item instanceof Message) {
                    Message message = service.getMessage(item.getItemId());
```

Instead of

```
FindItemResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = service.findItem(StandardFolder.INBOX, MessagePropertyPath.getAllPropertyPaths(), unReadMessages);
            for(Item item : response.getItems()) {
                if(item instanceof Message) {
                    Message message = (Message)item;
```

Answer (score 0):

if HasAttachment is false then there will be nothing in the Attachments collection. One thing to try would be Grab the MimeContent of the Message and then use another MIME library to parse Mime content for the image you want.

Cheers
Glen